# TIme limit in jmeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have the following case in jmeter and I would like to know why it happens.
I want a test in which 100 transactions per second are sent, this for 5 seconds, that is, 500 transactions in total.
The server resolves the 500 transactions without problems, but not in the time that I specified, rather it takes longer. why is this?
My config is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRzNO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration doesn't mean "100 transactions per second", it means that you have 500 users with 10 seconds ramp-up time

In other words JMeter will start 100 users each second and these users will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as fast as they can. The actual number of transactions per second will depend on your application response time. If application response time will be 1 second sharp - you will get 100 transactions per second, if it will be 2 seconds - you will get 50 transactions per second only, etc.

If you want to attempt to reach 100 transactions per second during 10 seconds I would rather recommend going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination:

[image]

Comment: oh I understand, thank you very much, I would like to know what the 150 that you enter in the concurrency thread group means, I really don't understand.
I really appreciate your help